# Grails: How can I change default view location?

Tags: grails, view, convention-over-configur

I've got controller `AdminTagController`. By default view will be located in `/adminTag` folder. Is it possible to change default folder for this controller to `/admin/view`? I can specify view for each method but it's not cool

Thank you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's possible to change it with the [afterInterceptor](http://grails.org/doc/2.2.1/ref/Controllers/afterInterceptor.html) of your controller. Check the example:

```
def afterInterceptor = { model, modelAndView ->
    println "Current view is ${modelAndView.viewName}"
    if (model.someVar) {
        modelAndView.viewName = "/mycontroller/someotherview"
    }
    println "View is now ${modelAndView.viewName}"
}
```

This is applied to all actions of your controller.

Comment: nice answer, I typically avoid interceptors as much as possible... +1

Answer (score 2):

In your case, I would do the heavy work in the controller, as only one class is impacted.

However, here is another way, using a custom [GroovyPageResourceLoader](http://grails.org/doc/latest/api/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/web/pages/GroovyPageResourceLoader.html#getResource%28java.lang.String%29).

That approach is typically used when your views are in a folder structure that doesn't follow Grails conventions. In your case, that would be overkill in my opinion.

However, here's the general idea:

**1. Create a class that extends the default groovyPageResourceLoader.**

Below is a **very raw** example.

```
class AdminGroovyPageResourceLoader extends GroovyPageResourceLoader {

 @Override Resource getResource(java.lang.String location) {
        if (location.contains ("/admin")) {
            return new FileSystemResource("PATH_TO_GSP_LOCATION_WITHOUT_FILE_EXTENSION")
        }

        return super.getResource(location)
 }
}
```

**2. Override the default groovyPageResourceLoader bean**

In *resources.groovy* or your plugin descriptor, override the *groovyPageResourceLoader* bean with your custom class.

A shorter path, might be some [metaclass](http://groovy.codehaus.org/JN3525-MetaClasses) *kung fu*, if you don't want to override the default Spring Bean.