# Grails 2.3.3 namespaced controller render view

Tags: grails, grails-2.0, grails-controller

For Grails 2.3.3, it allows same name controller in different package with namespaced controller according to http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/theWebLayer.html#namespacedControllers

So we have package like this:

```
/admin/FooController
/public/FooController
```

To keep consistent we want the view package like this:

```
/views/admin/foo/...
/views/public/foo/...
```

However, in the FooController action, if you don't hard code the render method. It will find the view in the

```
/views/foo/index....
```

It seems it can't take advantage of namespace. We have to hard code.

Anyone has good idea for that?

Comment: where you able to resolve your issue ?

Answer (score 3):

You can certainly do this. Take a look at this post by [Sérgio Michels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16810771/grails-how-can-i-change-default-view-location/16812149#16812149) shows how to render views from different directories using `afterInterceptor`.  The idea is to substitute the default view before its getting rendered.

So your controller will be something like this:

```
package test.xpublic

class FooController {
    static namespace = 'public'
    def afterInterceptor = { model, modelAndView ->         
        if (modelAndView.viewName.contains('index')) {
            modelAndView.viewName = "/public/index"
        }
    }
    def index() { }
}
```

You can be creative and make it smart to pick the right view, since `afterInterceptor` will be called for each action.

This will help you to render the view from your directory (views/admin or views/public). However, you also need to take care of the `UrlMappings`

```
class UrlMappings {
    static mappings = {
        "/foo/admin" {
            controller="foo"
             namespace = 'admin'
        }

        "/foo/public" {
            controller="foo"
            namespace = 'public'
        }
...
}
```

and finally on the links you need to pass the namespace.

```
<g:link controller='foo' namespace="admin" >Admin</g:link>
<g:link controller='foo' namespace="xpublic">Public</g:link>
```

A sample application is provided [here](https://github.com/alidadasb/GrailsNameSpace)

Answer (score 0):

At least with Grails 3.2.0 this is working out of the box. See http://docs.grails.org/latest/guide/theWebLayer.html#_selecting_views_for_namespaced_controllers for more details