# Grails domain resource uri mapping

Tags: grails

I'm trying to create an admin section in my grails app under `/admin`.  I've used the UrlMappings `group()` method to map to my `XyzAdmin` controller.

However, the edit, delete etc method links created by the scaffolding plugin point to the domain's ordinary URIs such as `/xyz/edit` `/xyz/delete` instead of `/admin/xyz/edit` etc.

Has anyone tackled this with the latest grails? (2.3.5)

Comment: Are you after something like [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19943271/grails-2-3-3-namespaced-controller-render-view/19944750#19944750)

Comment: latest grails is 2.3.6